# 10000000000 invalid character constant?

Tags: java

I'm creating a program that involves high powers of 10. How can I include the integer 10,000,000,000? I get an error that states 'Invalid character constant'.

```
int billion = '10000000000';
```

Comment: A character is just that -- a *character*. Ten billion isn't a character.

Comment: See also [*Underscores in Numeric Literals*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/underscores-literals.html).

Comment: int billion = 10000000000; **or** long billion = 10000000000; You must not use "" or ''.

Answer (score 4):

First, when you use single-quotes, you are making a character literal, and 10000000000 is not a valid character literal.

Second, that is bigger than the maximum `int` value, which is about 2 billion.  You'll want a `long` literal.

```
long tenbillion = 10000000000L;
```

If you're using Java 7+, you can [use underscores to visually separate the zeroes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/underscores-literals.html), and they don't affect the value.

```
long tenbillion = 10_000_000_000L;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a long:

```
long n = 100000000000L;
```

You can read about the different primitive data types (and their max values) [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can't. It is larger than

```
Integer.MAX_VALUE
```

You will need to use long instead

```
long billion = 10000000000l;
```